# Declared variable returns 'undefined'

Tags: javascript

I have tried everything I can think of to resolve the fact that my variable is returning 'undefined'.

I have gone console.log crazy checking everything is working as it should be and am now up against the proverbial brick wall.

The script is located just before the closing body tag.

I tried putting it in the head section of the page but this began returning NaN on the variables R and X.

Putting the variables just after the opening script tag before calling the function did likewise. I am somewhat new to javascript and would very much appreciate any help.

```
function DisplayInputValues() {

    var funds = document.getElementById("funds").value;
    var s = document.getElementById("sum").innerText;
    var j = document.getElementById('debt').value; //number of input fields

    var txtin; //class name of text input element
    var numin; // class name of number input element

    var L = 0;

    while (L < j) {

        console.log('funds= ' + funds); //just checking amount of funds shows correctly 
        console.log('debt = ' + s); //just checking Debt sum shows correctly
        console.log('Loop = ' + L);

        var userinput1 = document.getElementsByClassName('txtin')[L].value;
        console.log('Loop = ' + L + ' Text input = ' + userinput1);
        document.getElementById("showresults").innerHTML += userinput1 + "<br />";

        var userinput2 = document.getElementsByClassName('numin')[L].value;
        console.log('Loop = ' + L + ' Number input = ' + userinput2);
        document.getElementById("showresults").innerHTML += userinput2 +
            "<br/>" + 'Amount To Offer : ' + X + "<br />" + "<br />";

        var FP = funds / 100; // 1% of funds available
        var SP = s / 100; // 1% of debt total  
        var R = userinput2 / SP;
        R = R.toFixed(2);
        var X = FP * R;
        X = X.toFixed(2); //amount to offer in settlement

        console.log('Loop = ' + L + ' FP = ' + FP);
        console.log('Loop = ' + L + ' SP = ' + SP);
        console.log('Loop = ' + L + ' R = ' + R);
        console.log('Loop = ' + L + ' X = ' + X);
        console.log('Loop = ' + L + ' Amount to offer = ' + X);
        console.log('');

        L = L + 1;
    }
}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: What variable contains `undefined`, how do you know, what *should* it contain and why?

Comment: I'm with @ScottHunter, plus, txtin / numin both are never initialized and should be undefined, which probably causes document.getElementsByClassName to crash

Comment: There should have been a link to an image but it is nopt showing. Trying to fix this at the moment.

Comment: Also, an unrelated suggestion - use descriptive names for your variables. Why have `var txtin; //class name of text input element` when you can remove the need for the comment by just naming your variable `textInputValue` or something. You're not saving anything by naming variables a single letter.

Comment: I think using debugger to step thru this will reveal the issue

Comment: Picture link now showing.

Comment: Well X is undefined at the time you are trying to output it. You first output `'Amount To Offer : ' + X` then you define `var X = FP * R;`

Comment: So...what variable exactly goes there?

Comment: vlas - I take your point.

Comment: The picture shows in the console that the variable has a value that is returned in second loop whereas first loop returns undefined.

Comment: I am really having a hard time figuring out which variable will be `undefined` because I seriously don't know which one it would be. I'm looking at the picture and then trying to reverse engineer what's happening based on your code. The console logs only help in as much I know stuff has run but there is a lot of information to sort through. The completely obscure variable names don't help at all - what is `L`? What is `R`? Why are they manipulated at all? The initialisation, logging and manipulation of variables also makes me jump up and down the code just to track simple stuff.

Comment: With all that said, your problem is partly because of sloppy coding practices. When I finally realised `X` is what I should be looking at the problem is immediately apparent. You *show* `X` on the page first. Literally, you first show it. You *then* manipulate it and give it value. Of course it would be `undefined` when it doesn't have a value. You finally print it, at which point - yeah, there is a value but it's not what you put on the page. Next loop, you are printing the *previous* value of `X` which is also something that was confusing me in the console in the screenshot.

Comment: Thanks vlas. I mentioned that I'm new to javascript, hence the sloppy coding. I do intent to improve that. To apportion debt you need 1% of the funds available and 1% of each debt amount. Then Divide each debt by 1% of total debts to achieve a proportional 
percentage figure . Then Calculate the settlement amount each debt will be offered by multiplying 1% of available funds  by the the proportional percentage figure for each debt. The vars are just carrying out this math.

Comment: If we want to perform a voynich job, I could guess that the html is something like `<input id="funds" />
<div id="sum">456</div>
<input id="debt" value="2"/>
<input class="txtin" value="2"/>
<input class="numin" value="2"/>
<input class="txtin" value="2"/>
<input class="numin" value="2"/>
<div id="showresults">
</div> ` then X is undefined since is called before its first declaration. But I can't figure out what is the logic behind.

Comment: Not sure what you mean when you say...'can't figure out what is the logic behind.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Output everything after calculation

X is used before you declared it. In your original code you had

`document.getElementById("showresults").innerHTML += userinput2 + "<br/>" + 'Amount To Offer : ' + X + "<br />" + "<br />";`

before `X` was declared so of course it is going to give you undefined

I have changed the order of things so that X is first calculated then used

```
    var userinput1 = document.getElementsByClassName('txtin')[L].value;
    var userinput2 = document.getElementsByClassName('numin')[L].value;

    var FP = funds / 100; // 1% of funds available
    var SP = s / 100; // 1% of debt total  
    var R = userinput2 / SP;
    R = R.toFixed(2);
    var X = FP * R;
    X = X.toFixed(2); //amount to offer in settlement

    console.log('Loop = ' + L + ' Text input = ' + userinput1);
    document.getElementById("showresults").innerHTML += userinput1 + "<br />";

    console.log('Loop = ' + L + ' Number input = ' + userinput2);
    document.getElementById("showresults").innerHTML += userinput2 +
        "<br/>" + 'Amount To Offer : ' + X + "<br />" + "<br />";
```

Comment: Thank you Huangism. Works perfectly! Really appreciate that.